# '&' symbol in response - not displayed in soap UI

Tags: xslt, escaping, mule, soapui

I use SOAP UI to test mule application. I am trying to retrieve some values from database. One of the values is like 'A&B'. In XSLT, I was trying to use

```
<Element1>
   <xsl:value-of select="someTag" />
</Element1>
```

This returned a response like

```
<Element1>
A&amp;
</Element1>
```

I tried using

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="someTag" />
```

which printed correctly in the console

```
<Element1>A&B</Element1>
```

as expected but I could not see any kind of response in SOAP UI. Its completely blank.

Should I change any settings in SOAP UI to be able to view the response ?
Should I set outputEncoding attribute of xslt-transformer definition to something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not valid XML:

```
<Element1>A&B</Element1>
```

You have to return:

```
<Element1>A&amp;B</Element1>
```